# Continuous Section Break not deleting

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have a continuous section break that refuses to delete under normal circumstances: placing the cursor before it and hitting `delete`, placing the cursor after it and hitting `backspace`, highlighting and hitting either `backspace` or `delete`...nothing.

The only way I can get the section to go away is to delete everything before it all the way to the beginning of the document; not something I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Somehow the section break was attached to the heading 1 immediately following it. Removing both allowed me to remove the section break and all I had to retype was the chapter title.